# monaco editor - detect json schema validation error

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm using monaco editor with json schema validation according to standard example:
https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-configure-json-defaults

I'm emitting content change based on standard listener `onDidChangeModelContent`

I would like to prevent emitting content change, if there are schema validation error, but I can't seem to find a way to detect it.

Thank you for some pointers!